# How can I convert an android project originally coded in IDEA or Eclipse to Android Studio and add Gradle?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github, intellij-idea

I want to take on a sound recorder project from github: https://github.com/avipars/Android-SoundRecorder

But, it came from IDEA or Eclipse. I tried importing it through github, which didn't work. Then, I downloaded the ZIP and put it in android studio without much luck.

Android Studio won't recognize the file system and I want to get gradle working too.

So, how can I get it in Android Studio with Gradle working?

To clarify, I can get the project in Android Studio. It just won't compile.

Comment: How did you put it in android studio?

Comment: @shuvro import through VCS (Github) and also importing it offline through the regular system.

Comment: The project has a `.project` file. Definitely came from Eclipse. Adding Gradle after the fact is more hassle than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

Download the project in .zip form, then extract to your preferred workspace.

It looks like the project relies on two external libraries:

```
android.library.reference.1=../../android-libs/ListViewAnimations/library
android.library.reference.2=../../android-libs/UndoBar/library
```

Obviously, Android Studio won't know about these libraries while importing this project alone.  Remove the above lines from `project.properties` and add them later into your Android Studio project as dependencies or modules (if you can find them).  Otherwise, you can work out the dependencies in the code after importing.

Once you have removed those lines, from Android Studio, you can select "Import project"

[image: import]

Follow the import wizard and you should be brought into Android Studio with a summary of the import result.  From there you can muck with .git stuff and add back in any third party libraries that this source code may rely on.

Hope that helps!